# Automatic preview will not show View Controller code

Tags: swift, preview

I am in Xcode 6 and the view controller code was showing up under the automatic preview: now it is gone.

You cannot hook up the text fields under manual when selected. Where did it go, and how do I get it back? I have to keep deleting the VC and making new ones. is this a problem with Swift? I don't won't to have to keep deleting 10 VC and redoing them to code.

Comment: Make sure that you've selected the view of the controller you want to see; alternatively, you can use the top bar filesystem to navigate to the controller you want.

Comment: Yes the view is selected and the identity inspector is selected under the custom class - class is the correct ViewController.swift.All of this was working and then it just stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the answer but i had to type  the  @IBOutlet var firstNameTextField: UITextField! into the code under the manual preview instead of deleting the VC.swift.  I then added a button and typed the  @IBAction func savePointOfContactToDefault(sender: AnyObject){} and drag it to the button and the automatic preview now shows the code and you can now drag text, label, ect to the code. Ya seems to be a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with Swift; based on your answer, this may not be your problem, but you may not have your view controller file connected to your view in the storyboard (I am led to believe this by the fact that you have had to delete and re-add the file over and over again).

First, make sure that you've selected the view:

[image: Select the view]

Then, open the Inspector menu and go to the Identity section:

[image: Go to the Identity Inspector menu]

Under "Custom Class," make sure that "Class" is the name of your class in your VC file (see below): it should auto-complete as you type it in.

Then, in your view controller file, make sure that you have defined the class name properly, like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  // VC code
}
```